# Creating dynamic e-mail template

Tags: php, email, templates, cakephp

I'm looking for a way to create a good system to push datas into a email template.

I have an array with datas (the number of datas it depends on the number of zones in the email), and a simple html mail template :

Datas:

```
$mailDatas = array("mail title", "mail body", "mail footer");
```

And a very simple example of what a template should looks :

```
<div id="mail-container">
    <div id="mail-header">{data}</div>

    <img id="some design elements">


    <div id="mail-body">{data}</div>

    <div id="mail-footer">{data}</div>
</div>
```

What I need is replace the first `{data}` (it's a string) with the first data of my array `$mailDatas[0]`, and the second `{data}` with `$mailDatas[1]`, [...]

What is the best way to do that? I'm building a function to generate mail body with a template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CakePHP built-in Email library. You can declare your template, declare view, and pass variables to it.

For example, you can put your template in src/Template/Layout/Email/html/default.ctp, your view in src/Template/Email/html/welcome.ctp, and then call:

```
$email = new Email();
$email
    ->emailFormat('Html')
    ->template('welcome','default')
    ->to('johnny@example.com')
    ->viewVars($arrayOfVariables);
$email->send();
```

View vars are working exactly as in 'normal' views, so if you declare your array like:

```
$arrayOfVariables = ['varOne' => 'some text', 'varTwo' => 'other text'];
```

you can use it in view like this:

```
<span><?= $varOne ?></span>
```

For more info, please read docs: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html

Comment: That's the idea, but I don't want use key for my variables, only have multiple {data}. But I found a solution with preg_replace_callback :)

Comment: @ThomasRbt Depending on the order of the external input sounds like a very error prone solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run a foreach and inside that you need to create the HTML with with the maildatas variable

something like this

```
foreach ($maildatas as $maildata) { ?>
   <div id="mail-body"><?= $maildata; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: No, I'm looking to replace each {data} with a row from my data array

Comment: Than the loop will run on the array returned from your database after you query it.. the HTML creating logic will not change..just the array will now have dynamic content coming from the database